# Run commands on terminal using robot framework process

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get a list of android devices attached using adb devices -l.

But i'm not very sure how to run commands using process

Error given is --> FileNotFoundError, No such file or directory.

I think i'm missing out the syntax and would appreciate if anyone could take a look at this.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Process
Suite Teardown      Terminate All Processes     kill=True

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Run Process   adb devices -l
```

When i add *shell = True,*

the error message becomes --> Expected at least 1 non-named argument, got 0. Not too sure what argument i should put.

```
    Run Process   adb devices -l    shell=True
```

Referencing to: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake. It was a spacing issue.

I just need to tab 2 twice between the codes and it runs fine.

```
Run Process       adb devices -l      shell=True
```